# Closing div seems to disappear from the code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jekyll, cloudcannon

Here is my code: https://github.com/jhvanderschee/rafkappers

This closing div is not shown in FF or Chrome: https://github.com/jhvanderschee/rafkappers/blob/master/_includes/footer.html#L38

This can be seen here: http://www.rafkappers.nl. At localhost this does not happen. It is driving me nuts!!! How to fix this?

**EDIT:** I have added some extra source code examples, to illustrate the problem. Note, that I added the comments later, to prove the site is deployed (correctly).

*view-source: http://www.rafkappers.nl/ (live website with CloudCannon hosting)*

```
<!-- div after --><!-- div before -->
<div id="lightbox" style="width:100%;height:100%;" onclick="closeimage();">
```

*https://app.cloudcannon.com/editor#/site/21927/browser/_includes/footer.html (source code in CC)*

```
</footer>
<!-- div after --></div><!-- div before -->
<div id="lightbox" style="width:100%;height:100%;" onclick="closeimage();">
```

*view-source: http://localhost:4000/*

```
</footer>
<!-- div after --></div><!-- div before -->
<div id="lightbox" style="width:100%;height:100%;" onclick="closeimage();">
```

Comment: From the sounds of it, you need to deploy your code. Are you sure the files on your server match your master branch?

Comment: PS. @drheart Thank you, but the deploy went fine. You can check the master branch yourself to verify. This problem might be related to the Jekyll version, but I am not sure... Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just got feedback from Mike from CloudCannon: It's a problem that CloudCannon is causing. He wrote:

*"In _includes/footer.html you're closing a  which has been opened elsewhere. Usually this wouldn't be a problem but you also have editable classes on this file. For an editable class to work we need to parse an html file on it's own. When we do this on _includes/footer.html, the parser will see there's an extra  and remove it as it was never opened."*

There are two solutions:

- Always open and close HTML elements in the same file or
- Don't use editable classes where you open/close html elements across multiple files.

Comment: Very interesting. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like whatever tools used by CloudCannon to build your website, is removing that `div`.

I cloned your repository on GitHub, and ran a simple `jekyll build` to look at the generated file, and it behaves as expected.

[image: screenshot]

I've put a copy of your site on a GitHub repo to let GitHub pages run Jekyll, and it also works as expected*

https://sandboxorg.github.io/rafkappers/
https://github.com/sandboxorg/rafkappers

(*) images don't show because you didn't prepare it to have base url, you should fix that

One thing that I noticed, is that the `div` that seems to be missing, is the `div` that corresponds to the closing of the `<div id="wrapall">` and just before that, there's another `div`, `<div id="nonsplash">` which is never closed. So you may want to try to close this `nonsplash` `div` and see if that fixes it (assuming some tool is validating the HTML output from Jekyll and making changes to it).

If that doesn't help, your best bet is to contact CloudCannon support and show that when using Jekyll directly or GitHub pages, this behavior doesn't happen.

Comment: Thank you for your analysis and good advice. I have contacted support and posted their answer below.